# Is there a way to force sub value to have a field that match with a key of the object?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type where value must match a key of the object. Is there any way to do that in typescript ?

```js
type Foo = {
    [key: string]: {
        target: keyof Foo
    }
};

const foo: Foo = {
    a: {target: "b"},
    b: {target: "c"},
    c: {target: "b"},
}

const goo: Foo = {
    a: {target: "any value"}, // I want this to show an error
    b: {target: "c"},
    c: {target: "b"},
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. But don't seem elegant.

```js
type Goo<T> = { target: T };
type Foo<K extends string, T extends K> = {[k in K]: Goo<T>};

F({
    a: {target: "a"},
    g: {target: "a"}
});

function F<K extends string, T extends K>(foo: Foo<K, T>) {

}
```